# Booting into Xen with grub2-mkconfig 2.03 on centos8 x86_64

Tags: centos, grub, xen, grub2-mkconfig

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.0-394.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 31 16:19:11 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

grub2-mkconfig (GRUB) 2.03
```

On my centos8, I have installed `centos-release-openstack-xena.noarch`

But I cannot boot into Xen, please help.

Theoretically, after installing Xen, I should only run

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

As my `/etc/grub.d` has a linux_xen file and antoher large number of files hanging there:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /etc/grub.d/
00_header  01_users              10_linux               11_linux_xen       20_linux_xen     30_os-prober      35_fwupd   41_custom
00_tuned   08_fallback_counting  10_reset_boot_success  12_menu_auto_hide  20_ppc_terminfo  30_uefi-firmware  40_custom  README
```

(`11_linux_xen` is a symlink I created pointing to `20_linux_xen`)

Unfortunately, `grub.cfg` will have nothing in the `linux_xen` section.

I added `echo << EOF` and `EOF` to the `linux_xen` file and I got some errors, but I wonder if debugging this complexity is the best way forward or if there is something simpler I can do.

`/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen` file contents:

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e

# grub-mkconfig helper script.
# Copyright (C) 2006,2007,2008,2009,2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# GRUB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# GRUB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GRUB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

cat << EOF
prefix="/usr"
exec_prefix="/usr"
datarootdir="/usr/share"

. "$pkgdatadir/grub-mkconfig_lib"

export TEXTDOMAIN=grub
export TEXTDOMAINDIR="${datarootdir}/locale"

CLASS="--class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen"

if [ "x${GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR}" = "x" ] ; then
  OS="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
else
  OS="${GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR}"
  CLASS="--class $(echo ${GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR} | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | cut -d' ' -f1|LC_ALL=C sed 's,[^[:alnum:]_],_,g') ${CLASS}"
fi

# loop-AES arranges things so that /dev/loop/X can be our root device, but
# the initrds that Linux uses don't like that.
case ${GRUB_DEVICE} in
  /dev/loop/*|/dev/loop[0-9])
    GRUB_DEVICE=`losetup ${GRUB_DEVICE} | sed -e "s/^[^(]*(\([^)]\+\)).*/\1/"`
  ;;
esac

# Default to disabling partition uuid support to maintian compatibility with
# older kernels.
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_PARTUUID=${GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_PARTUUID-true}

# btrfs may reside on multiple devices. We cannot pass them as value of root= parameter
# and mounting btrfs requires user space scanning, so force UUID in this case.
if ( [ "x${GRUB_DEVICE_UUID}" = "x" ] && [ "x${GRUB_DEVICE_PARTUUID}" = "x" ] ) \
    || ( [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID}" = "xtrue" ] \
    && [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_PARTUUID}" = "xtrue" ] ) \
    || ( ! test -e "/dev/disk/by-uuid/${GRUB_DEVICE_UUID}" \
    && ! test -e "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/${GRUB_DEVICE_PARTUUID}" ) \
    || ( test -e "${GRUB_DEVICE}" && uses_abstraction "${GRUB_DEVICE}" lvm ); then
  LINUX_ROOT_DEVICE=${GRUB_DEVICE}
elif [ "x${GRUB_DEVICE_UUID}" = "x" ] \
    || [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID}" = "xtrue" ]; then
  LINUX_ROOT_DEVICE=PARTUUID=${GRUB_DEVICE_PARTUUID}
else
  LINUX_ROOT_DEVICE=UUID=${GRUB_DEVICE_UUID}
fi

# Allow overriding GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.
if [ "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_XEN_REPLACE}" ]; then
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_XEN_REPLACE}"
fi
if [ "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_XEN_REPLACE_DEFAULT}" ]; then
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_XEN_REPLACE_DEFAULT}"
fi

case x"$GRUB_FS" in
    xbtrfs)
    if [ "x${SUSE_BTRFS_SNAPSHOT_BOOTING}" = "xtrue" ]; then
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} \${extra_cmdline}"
    else
    rootsubvol="`make_system_path_relative_to_its_root /`"
    rootsubvol="${rootsubvol#/}"
    if [ "x${rootsubvol}" != x ]; then
        GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootflags=subvol=${rootsubvol} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX}"
    fi
    fi;;
    xzfs)
    rpool=`${grub_probe} --device ${GRUB_DEVICE} --target=fs_label 2>/dev/null || true`
    bootfs="`make_system_path_relative_to_its_root / | sed -e "s,@$,,"`"
    LINUX_ROOT_DEVICE="ZFS=${rpool}${bootfs}"
    ;;
esac

title_correction_code=

linux_entry ()
{
  os="$1"
  version="$2"
  xen_version="$3"
  type="$4"
  args="$5"
  xen_args="$6"
  if [ -z "$boot_device_id" ]; then
      boot_device_id="$(grub_get_device_id "${GRUB_DEVICE}")"
  fi
  if [ x$type != xsimple ] ; then
      if [ x$type = xrecovery ] ; then
      title="$(gettext_printf "%s, with Xen %s and Linux %s (recovery mode)" "${os}" "${xen_version}" "${version}")"
      else
      title="$(gettext_printf "%s, with Xen %s and Linux %s" "${os}" "${xen_version}" "${version}")"
      fi
      replacement_title="$(echo "Advanced options for ${OS}" | sed 's,>,>>,g')>$(echo "$title" | sed 's,>,>>,g')"
      if [ x"Xen ${xen_version}>$title" = x"$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" ]; then
         quoted="$(echo "$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" | grub_quote)"
         title_correction_code="${title_correction_code}if [ \"x\$default\" = '$quoted' ]; then default='$(echo "$replacement_title" | grub_quote)'; fi;"
         grub_warn "$(gettext_printf "Please don't use old title \`%s' for GRUB_DEFAULT, use \`%s' (for versions before 2.00) or \`%s' (for 2.00 or later)" "$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" "$replacement_title" "gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id>gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id")"
      fi
      echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  else
      title="$(gettext_printf "%s, with Xen hypervisor" "${os}")"
      echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  fi
  if [ x$type != xrecovery ] ; then
      save_default_entry | grub_add_tab | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  fi

  if [ -z "${prepare_boot_cache}" ]; then
    prepare_boot_cache="$(prepare_grub_to_access_device ${GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT} | grub_add_tab)"
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "${prepare_boot_cache}" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  xmessage="$(gettext_printf "Loading Xen %s ..." ${xen_version})"
  lmessage="$(gettext_printf "Loading Linux %s ..." ${version})"
  sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
    echo    '$(echo "$xmessage" | grub_quote)'
        if [ "\$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "\$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
            xen_rm_opts=
        else
            xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
        fi
    insmod ${module_loader}
    insmod ${xen_loader}
    ${xen_loader}   ${rel_xen_dirname}/${xen_basename} placeholder ${xen_args} \${xen_rm_opts}
    echo    '$(echo "$lmessage" | grub_quote)'
    ${module_loader}    ${rel_dirname}/${basename} placeholder root=${linux_root_device_thisversion} ro ${args}
EOF
  if test -n "${initrd}" ; then
    # TRANSLATORS: ramdisk isn't identifier. Should be translated.
    message="$(gettext_printf "Loading initial ramdisk ...")"
    sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
    echo    '$(echo "$message" | grub_quote)'
    insmod ${module_loader}
    ${module_loader}    --nounzip   ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}
EOF
  fi
  sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
}
EOF
}

linux_list=
for i in /boot/vmlinu[xz]-* /vmlinu[xz]-* /boot/kernel-*; do
    if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i"; then
        basename=$(basename $i)
    version=$(echo $basename | sed -e "s,^[^0-9]*-,,g")
    dirname=$(dirname $i)
    config=
    for j in "${dirname}/config-${version}" "${dirname}/config-${alt_version}" "/etc/kernels/kernel-config-${version}" ; do
        if test -e "${j}" ; then
        config="${j}"
        break
        fi
    done
        if (grep -qx "CONFIG_XEN_DOM0=y" "${config}" 2> /dev/null || grep -qx "CONFIG_XEN_PRIVILEGED_GUEST=y" "${config}" 2> /dev/null); then linux_list="$linux_list $i" ; fi
    fi
done
if [ "x${linux_list}" = "x" ] ; then
    exit 0
fi

file_is_not_sym () {
    case "$1" in
    */xen-syms-*)
        return 1;;
    *)
        return 0;;
    esac
}

xen_list=
for i in /boot/xen*; do
    if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" && file_is_not_sym "$i" ; then xen_list="$xen_list $i" ; fi
done
prepare_boot_cache=
boot_device_id=

title_correction_code=

machine=`uname -m`

case "$machine" in
    i?86) GENKERNEL_ARCH="x86" ;;
    mips|mips64) GENKERNEL_ARCH="mips" ;;
    mipsel|mips64el) GENKERNEL_ARCH="mipsel" ;;
    arm*) GENKERNEL_ARCH="arm" ;;
    *) GENKERNEL_ARCH="$machine" ;;
esac

# Extra indentation to add to menu entries in a submenu. We're not in a submenu
# yet, so it's empty. In a submenu it will be equal to '\t' (one tab).
submenu_indentation=""

is_top_level=true

while [ "x${xen_list}" != "x" ] ; do
    list="${linux_list}"
    current_xen=`version_find_latest $xen_list`
    xen_basename=`basename ${current_xen}`
    xen_dirname=`dirname ${current_xen}`
    rel_xen_dirname=`make_system_path_relative_to_its_root $xen_dirname`
    xen_version=`echo $xen_basename | sed -e "s,.gz$,,g;s,^xen-,,g"`
    if [ -z "$boot_device_id" ]; then
    boot_device_id="$(grub_get_device_id "${GRUB_DEVICE}")"
    fi
    if [ "x$is_top_level" != xtrue ]; then
    echo "  submenu '$(gettext_printf "Xen hypervisor, version %s" "${xen_version}" | grub_quote)' \$menuentry_id_option 'xen-hypervisor-$xen_version-$boot_device_id' {"
    fi
    if ($grub_file --is-arm64-efi $current_xen); then
    xen_loader="xen_hypervisor"
    module_loader="xen_module"
    else
    if ($grub_file --is-x86-multiboot2 $current_xen); then
        xen_loader="multiboot2"
        module_loader="module2"
    else
        xen_loader="multiboot"
        module_loader="module"
        fi
    fi
    while [ "x$list" != "x" ] ; do
    linux=`version_find_latest $list`
    gettext_printf "Found linux image: %s\n" "$linux" >&2
    basename=`basename $linux`
    dirname=`dirname $linux`
    rel_dirname=`make_system_path_relative_to_its_root $dirname`
    version=`echo $basename | sed -e "s,^[^0-9]*-,,g"`
    alt_version=`echo $version | sed -e "s,\.old$,,g"`
    linux_root_device_thisversion="${LINUX_ROOT_DEVICE}"

    initrd=
    for i in "initrd.img-${version}" "initrd-${version}.img" "initrd-${version}.gz" \
       "initrd-${version}" "initramfs-${version}.img" \
       "initrd.img-${alt_version}" "initrd-${alt_version}.img" \
       "initrd-${alt_version}" "initramfs-${alt_version}.img" \
       "initramfs-genkernel-${version}" \
       "initramfs-genkernel-${alt_version}" \
       "initramfs-genkernel-${GENKERNEL_ARCH}-${version}" \
       "initramfs-genkernel-${GENKERNEL_ARCH}-${alt_version}" ; do
        if test -e "${dirname}/${i}" ; then
        initrd="$i"
        break
        fi
    done
    if test -n "${initrd}" ; then
        gettext_printf "Found initrd image: %s\n" "${dirname}/${initrd}" >&2
    else
    # "UUID=" magic is parsed by initrds.  Since there's no initrd, it can't work here.
        if [ "x${GRUB_DEVICE_PARTUUID}" = "x" ] \
        || [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_PARTUUID}" = "xtrue" ]; then

        linux_root_device_thisversion=${GRUB_DEVICE}
        else
        linux_root_device_thisversion=PARTUUID=${GRUB_DEVICE_PARTUUID}
        fi
    fi

    if [ "x$is_top_level" = xtrue ] && [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU}" != xy ]; then
        linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" "${xen_version}" simple \
        "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}" "${GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT}"

        submenu_indentation="$grub_tab$grub_tab"
    
        if [ -z "$boot_device_id" ]; then
        boot_device_id="$(grub_get_device_id "${GRUB_DEVICE}")"
        fi
            # TRANSLATORS: %s is replaced with an OS name
        echo "submenu '$(gettext_printf "Advanced options for %s (with Xen hypervisor)" "${OS}" | grub_quote)' \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id' {"
    echo "  submenu '$(gettext_printf "Xen hypervisor, version %s" "${xen_version}" | grub_quote)' \$menuentry_id_option 'xen-hypervisor-$xen_version-$boot_device_id' {"
       is_top_level=false
    fi

    linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" "${xen_version}" advanced \
        "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}" "${GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT}"
    if [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY}" != "xtrue" ]; then
        linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" "${xen_version}" recovery \
        "single ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX}" "${GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN}"
    fi

    list=`echo $list | tr ' ' '\n' | fgrep -vx "$linux" | tr '\n' ' '`
    done
    if [ x"$is_top_level" != xtrue ]; then
    echo '  }'
    fi
    xen_list=`echo $xen_list | tr ' ' '\n' | fgrep -vx "$current_xen" | tr '\n' ' '`
done

# If at least one kernel was found, then we need to
# add a closing '}' for the submenu command.
if [ x"$is_top_level" != xtrue ]; then
  echo '}'
fi

echo "$title_correction_code"

EOF
```

Error message generated when running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg` :

```
[root@localhost ~]# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
losetup: /dev/nvme0n1p3: failed to use device: No such device
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: make_system_path_relative_to_its_root: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: make_system_path_relative_to_its_root: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: grub_get_device_id: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: gettext_printf: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: gettext_printf: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: grub_quote: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: grub_quote: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: gettext_printf: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: grub_quote: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: gettext_printf: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: grub_quote: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: prepare_grub_to_access_device: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: grub_add_tab: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: gettext_printf: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: gettext_printf: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: grub_quote: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 20: grub_quote: command not found
/etc/grub.d/11_linux_xen: line 158: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

This question was also published at: https://xcp-ng.org/forum/topic/6113/booting-into-xen-with-grub2-mkconfig-2-03-on-centos8-x86_64

And: https://forums.centos.org/viewforum.php?f=54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The description](https://centos.pkgs.org/8-stream/centos-extras-x86_64/centos-release-openstack-xena-1-1.el8.noarch.rpm.html) for package `centos-release-openstack-xena.noarch` reads:

> yum Configs and basic docs for OpenStack as delivered via the CentOS Cloud SIG.

The fact that the package name has the `.noarch` suffix suggests there is nothing directly bootable in this package, as it means the contents are processor-architecture independent, i.e. only scripts, documentation and/or data.

The name `xena` also does not refer to Xen as such: it is the release codename of the October 2021 release of OpenStack.

Installing `centos-release-openstack-xena.noarch` is but the first preparatory step in installing OpenStack. If that's what you are planning, then you should start reading the [OpenStack installation guide](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/). You are now in position to *begin* installing the various OpenStack component services.

But if you are looking for **the virtualization hypervisor named Xen**, then you have installed a wrong package.

Note that [RHEL/CentOS 8 has no support for Xen PV or PVH modes at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617637/258991), as RedHat favors KVM over Xen. You could run CentOS 8's standard kernel in HVM mode, but I've understood that would probably be less efficient than the PV/PVH modes. Or you could install `kernel-ml` from [ElRepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/HomePage); that would allow you to run CentOS 8 within Xen, but would be a *necessary but not sufficient* step in setting up a CentOS 8-based Xen host.

Comment: Thank you! I’m looking for Xen. But ‘yum search xen’ brings only this package.

Comment: Please see my edit just now.